# How to control one of multiple instances of a prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiple-instances

My "game" read a file XML, identify some elements and instance him at runtime. This instances is of a prefab.
So, I have a loop with a variable "ins" that create the instances:

```html
ins = (GameObject)Instantiate (this.MyPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

I would like, for example, to click on a instance and change its color and not on all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that`Update()` calls `Click()` in every frame. So, whenever you press the mouse button `if( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )` becomes true for every prefab and they all process the click event, irrespective of whether they  were clicked on or not.

The solution would be to add a Collider component to your prefab and implement OnMouseDown() in ButtonDiagram class to detect mouse clicks on the object. Something like :

```
public class ButtonDiagram : MonoBehaviour
{
    // rest of your code

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Click!");
    }
}
```

Unity's documentation:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: @filran, glad to help a fellow programmer :)

Comment: Now, after to change scene, the Directional Light seems that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an array of gameobjects.

Do a foreach loop and add each instance to the your array. Then you could do ins[0].DOSOMETHING or, simpler, have the prefabs you're instantiating have a script on it then accepts mouse clicks or other input and that will affect only the gameobject/prefab that the user interacts with.

Comment: Bryan, I created a array, but yet the click not apply on one instance, but on all.

void Update ()
 {
  foreach( GameObject i in instances ){
   i.GetComponentInChildren<MyPrefab>().Click();
  }
 }

Comment: Do you have scripts attached to each prefab that handle onclick (or on touch) events? And in the script for each prefab are you using the 'this' keyword. Instead of the array just instantiate each prefab and make sure each prefab has its own script that has an onclick definition.

Comment: Bryan, sorry, but I am beginner. I will post my code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Program : MonoBehaviour
{

 private Diagram diagram { get; set; }
 public string arquivoXMI;
 public GameObject ButtonDiagramGameObject;
 private const int SPACEX = 2;
 private GameObject ins;
 public ArrayList instances{ get; private set; }

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
  this.diagram = new Diagram (arquivoXMI);

  ButtonForEachSequenceDiagram ();
 }


 //BUTTON FOR EACH SEQUENCE DIAGRAM
 private void ButtonForEachSequenceDiagram()
 {
  instances = new ArrayList ();

  if (this.diagram.SequenceDiagrams.Count > 0) {
   float increment = (this.ButtonDiagramGameObject.transform.localScale.x / 2) + SPACEX;
   float position = 0;

   foreach( Sequence s in this.diagram.SequenceDiagrams )
   {
    float posBDx = position;
    float posBDy = this.ButtonDiagramGameObject.transform.position.y;
    float posBDz = this.ButtonDiagramGameObject.transform.position.z;

    Vector3 posButtonDiagram = new Vector3 (posBDx, posBDy, posBDz);
    ins = (GameObject)Instantiate (this.ButtonDiagramGameObject, posButtonDiagram, Quaternion.identity) ;
    ins.GetComponentInChildren<ButtonDiagram> ().NameDiagram ( s.Name );

    instances.Add(ins);

    position += increment;
   }
  }
 }
 

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
  foreach( GameObject i in instances ){
   i.GetComponentInChildren<ButtonDiagram>().Click();
  }
 }
 
}





using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonDiagram : MonoBehaviour {

 public TextMesh Name;
 public GameObject MyCube;
 private string nameDiagram;
 private float random;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
//  random = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
//  NameDiagram = random.ToString();
  Name.text = nameDiagram;

 }


 public void NameDiagram( string nome ){
  this.nameDiagram = nome;
 }


 public void Click(){
  if( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
  {
   Debug.Log("Click!");
  }
 }


 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
}
```

Comment: Make a new script called 'clickingscript' (or whatever you want to name it). In script add your variables and for the clicking part you need this line: void OnMouseDown(){ //do something }. I'm not sure if Click() is correct. In the unity editor attach the script to the prefab.

Comment: Bryan, I tested with Collider and is working. Anyway, thanks a lot by your help.